# session.createConsumer() returns null

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jms

I am trying to retrieve messages from queue based on correlation ID using the  method `session.createConsumer(queue,messageSelector)` but it is returning `null`.

Below is the complete syntax

```
MessageConsumer queueConsumer = queueSession.createConsumer(destinationQueue, "CorrID='"+correlationID+"'");
```

Can someone suggest what could be the reason? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the standard JMS correlation ID, use `"JMSCorrelationID='" + correlationID + "'"` - see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html for a full description of Message Selectors, search for "Message header field references".

Comment: my requirement is to generate Correlation ID's and push it to queue along with the various messages and then retrieve the messages from the queue using the Correlation ID. How to achieve this? Not sure if the Correlation ID i am referring to is the standard JMS correlation ID. Since i am doing this in Spring i need a JMS producer and consumer  class and not a listener because in listener there is no provision to set filter criterion and therefore all the messages get consumed at once,